# Import a column from excel into python and run autocorrelation on it

Tags: python

I have a 1 column excel file. I want to import all the values it has in a variable x (something like `x=[1,2,3,4.5,-6.....]`), then use this variable to run `numpy.correlate(x,x,mode='full')` to get autocorrelation, after I `import numpy`.

When I manually enter `x=[1,2,3...]`, it does the job fine, but when I try to copy paste all the values in `x=[]`, it gives me a NameError: name 'NO' is not defined.

Can someone tell me how to go around doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas to import a CSV file with the `pd.read_csv` function.